# Does MiCA have any impacts on merchants (and their customers)?

Tags: european-union, consumer-protection, cryptocurrency, euro

The [EU just passed MiCA (Markets in Crypto-Assets)](https://www.coindesk.com/policy/2023/04/20/eu-parliament-approves-crypto-licensing-funds-transfer-rules/) to regulate crypto assets.

One classification of crypto assets is a cryptocurrency, which includes digital currencies like Bitcoin.

Most of the coverage I've seen about MiCA covers how these new regulations will affect cryptocurrency exchanges and financial institutions. But what about the most common use of currencies: exchanges of value between a customer and a merchant?

How does MiCA affect the customer and the merchant when the customer purchases a bag of flour from the merchant for 2,00 EUR? What regulations from MiCA apply to both [a] the customer [b] the merchant in this transaction?

Comment: "the most common use of currencies: exchanges of value between a customer and a merchant?" Not exactly on point, but is that actually the most common way it is used? I've not observed that but I'm not claiming it doesn't happen.